# Why no CSRF cookie is generated for my request?

Tags: java, spring, cookies, csrf, spring-rest

I'm trying to activate the CSRF cookies in Spring. So I have the following class:

**SecurityAdapter.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception
    {
        http
            .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    }
}
```

Since I'm trying to implement a REST web service (no HTML or anything), I believe the first request to the server should be a GET one because other request types will require `XSRF-TOKEN` and we don't have that yet.

So when I send a GET request, I expect to receive some cookies in response (I've been a good boy after all!). But I don't get any.

Here's the rest of the project files:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Controller.Java**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class Controller
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/first", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity get()
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("first");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/second", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity post()
    {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("second");
    }
}
```

When I call the `second` method (of course in POST method), I get:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1481500256460,
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.",
  "path": "/second"
}
```

But when I get the `first` method in GET while it is called, I don't get any cookies to use and call the `second` method!

What am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested your code and I am getting `csrf` token in cookie. I verified the GET method in Chrome browser and checked the cookies tab. There is XSRF-TOKEN present which is returned by service. In order to print the csrf token returned by service, I modified your `first` method in Controller like below. Please test it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/first", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity get(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
    System.out.println(token.getHeaderName()+" = "+token.getToken());
    return ResponseEntity.ok("first");
}
```

One more thing. As you are using Spring Boot you should use `spring-boot-starter-security`, instead of individual Spring Security dependencies. Dependencies in your `pom.xml` should be like below.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks, it turned out I was getting the cookie but Postman does not show it for some reason! I tested it with Chrome, and it was there all along. And thanks for the Maven tip.

Comment: @Mehran You need to install a Chrome extension called "Postman Interceptor" so as to see the CSRF-TOKEN cookie in your response in Postman.